# React Hot Module Replacement not loading styles

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I'm having some issues with HMR where its successfully reloading every time I make changes to either one of my jsx files or even my css files. However, the reload loads the pages with none of my styling. Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some code? Because it might be that you forgot to import your styles into the index.js, or that you did not configure webpack to process your styles...

You can take a look at this repo and compare it against what you have: https://github.com/matheus4lves/react-pagination

Pay special attention to theses lines:

webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
      // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
      "style-loader",
      // Translates CSS into CommonJS
      "css-loader",
      // Compiles Sass to CSS
      "sass-loader",
    ],
  },
```

index.js

```
import "./styles/styles.scss";
import "./styles/pagination.scss";
```